# Glassfish Server not loading servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

```
I am getting a 404 when I navigate to http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/generic
but not when I go to http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/test.jsp
```

I create the war file by navigating to myWebApp and typing "jar -cvf myWebApp.war ."

I put it in the glassfish autodeploy folder. **Is there anything I'm missing?**

I have a standard file structure

```
--> "myWebApp/"
||--> "WEB_INF/"
||||--> "classes/"
||||||--> "genericServlet.class"
||||--> "lib/" {empty}
||--> "test.jsp"
```

Here is genericServlet.class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.GenericServlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet(name = "GenericServletDemoServlet", 
    urlPatterns = { "/generic" },
    initParams = {
        @WebInitParam(name="admin", value="Harry Taciak"),
        @WebInitParam(name="email", value="admin@example.com")
    }
)
public class GenericServletDemoServlet extends GenericServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 62500890L;

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest request, 
            ServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        ServletConfig servletConfig = getServletConfig();
        String admin = servletConfig.getInitParameter("admin");
        String email = servletConfig.getInitParameter("email");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.print("<html><head></head><body>" + 
                "Admin:" + admin + 
                "<br/>Email:" + email +
                "</body></html>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it seems, that you need to map the servlet in the web.xml.
something like:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>generic</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>servlet.package.GenericServletDemoServlet</servlet-class></servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>generic</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/generic</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I'm using annotations so I shouldn't have to

Answer (score -1):

With gradle + annotations + jakarta 9.0 + Glassfish 7, remove the web.xml file.